# Django exclude url pattern

Tags: python, django, regex, routes, django-urls

i have a basic django app and want to exclude a route from matching other routes with similar structure
below is my `urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'blogs'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name = 'index'),
    path('create', views.create, name = 'create'),
    path('<str:handle>', views.show, name = 'blogs'),
]
```

i want `path('create'), views.create, name = 'create')` to go to the create blog page, and `path('<str:handle>', views.show, name = 'blogs'),` to go to the details page for a blog.

i get a 404 blog not found error when i navigate to `http://localhost:8000/blogs/create`

how do i exclude the `create` from matching the `<str:handle>` for a blog detail page?

**Edit**
the url.py for the main app urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('blogs/', include(('blogs.urls', 'blogs'), namespace = 'blogs')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: Can you include the rest of your urls that include `create`? Putting `create` before `blogs` will probably work

Comment: i did, but still getting the error

Comment: You updated your urls to match the code above and `/blogs/create` still goes to the `views.show` view? That does not sound likely. Can you post the rest of your urls?

Comment: yes please. ```/blogs/create/``` goes to the ```views.create``` view but ```/blogs/create``` goes to the ```views.show``` view

Answer (score 0):

Option 1

Did you put your app in installed app in project settings.py.

Option 2.

You need to mention the blogs/urls.py files in project urls.py files.

Comment: yes i did, both options...